# How to draw random colours dots?

Tags: inkscape, brush, pencil

How can I draw dots with a specific size and random colors?

Is it possible to create a brush or something similar to do it?

With the pencil if I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click I can draw a black dot, but is always black and same size. Is it possible to change the default size and color of the dot?

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Use the Spray Tool, then the Tweak Tool.

1. Draw a circle or any object. Add a fill. Select it, and choose the Spray Tool
2. In the tool options along the top, make sure you choose the "Spray Copies" mode, otherwise the recolouring steps won't work
3. Click and drag to spray the selected object
4. When you have finished, choose the Tweak Tool, and in the tool options along the top, choose the "Jitter colours" option.  And Enable the H and S options (Hue and Saturation).
5. Select All (CTRL+A) and paint with the Tweak Tool to randomize the colours.

[image]

Comment: Thank you !!! 

I used this way.

I've also found this other video explaining other way:
https://framadrive.org/s/eFSPF7cqxWQJynX

Comment: 'Found' is maybe not the right term - you asked in the inkscapeforum, too, and that is where you got my reply ;-)